# EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS from included file

Tags: org-mode, org-export

If I have a heading with a tag `:noexportoninclude:` on a file *to_be_included.org*, and I include it on another file which has `#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexportoninclude`, the tagged heading will be exported anyway.

How can I have EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS exclude tags from included files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the correct syntax is `#+EXCLUDE_TAGS:`, and not `#+EXPORT_EXCLUDE_TAGS:`. I could not find this on the online documentation, but running `C-h v org-export-exclude-tags` will tell us that:

> This option can also be set with the EXCLUDE_TAGS keyword.

*Emacs 25.3.2 and Org-mode 9.1.7*

Comment: It's in [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#Export-settings).

Comment: do you see anything wrong in this? #+EXCLUDE_TAGS: :tasklist:noexport:

Comment: yes. You should write `#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: tasklist noexport`

Comment: I'll never get org syntaxes. tas are normal colon seperated